# Convergence of a sequence of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff metric space. I have a set of three sequences with the following properties. $\{h_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^\infty(m)$, $m$ is a probability measure such that $\{h_n\}$'s are uniformly norm bounded and $\{h_n\}$ converges to $h$- $m$ almost everywhere. Now for each $n$, there is a sequence of continuous functions $\{f^n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $|f^n_k(x)|\leq ||h_n||_\infty$- $m$-almost everywhere and $f^n_k(x)\rightarrow h_n(x)$ $m$ almost everywhere. Also there is a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_k\}$ such that $|f_k(x)|\leq ||h||_\infty$ and $m$-almost everywhere and $f_k(x)\rightarrow h(x)$ $m$ almost everywhere. Can I conclude that $f^n_k\rightarrow f_k$ in norm as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since that would imply that a norm bounded sequence of continuous functions converging a.e. converges in $\infty$-norm by taking $f_k^n = h_n$ and $f_k = h$. This is false.

For a concrete example, consider $X = [0,1]$ equipped with its usual metric and the Lebesgue measure, which I denote by $m$. Let $$h_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - nx, \qquad x \in [0,\frac1n] \\0, \qquad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
Then $\|h_n\|_\infty = 1$ and $h_n \to 0$ $m$-a.e. We can then take $f_k^n = h_n$ and $f_k = h = 0$ to get a trivial example where the result doesn't hold.